# Why does WinDbg show different function origin than MSDN?

Tags: windows, windbg

I've been debugging a program where I had to set a breakpoint on `CreateProcessAsUserW` function. The Microsoft Docs for this function (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/processthreadsapi/nf-processthreadsapi-createprocessasuserw) state that the function is located (exported) from `Advapi32.dll`. But WinDbg "states" that the function in located in `KernelBase.dll`, as far as I correctly understand these results (coming from WinDbg):

```
0:000> dt advapi32!CreateProc*
0:000> dt kernelbase!CreateProcessAsUser*
00007ffc504da520  KERNELBASE!CreateProcessAsUserA
00007ffc504da550  KERNELBASE!CreateProcessAsUserW
```

Why is that, why are the results different since both sources are trustworthy?

Comment: Do you have symbols loaded for both DLL files?

Comment: `CreateProcessAsUserW` really exported by advapi32.dll too. but here small stub which call to kernelbase.dll `CreateProcessAsUserW`

Comment: @Dai I have my symbols path set and WinDbg loaded them the first time I checked these libraries

Answer (score 1, accepted):

both kernelbase.dll and advapi32.dll exports the Function CreateProcessAsuserA/W

```
C:\Windows\System32>dumpbin /exports KernelBase.dll | find /I "AsU"
        216   D0 001BEA00 CreateProcessAsUserA
        217   D1 001BEA40 CreateProcessAsUserW
        222   D6 001AEA00 CreatePseudoConsoleAsUser

C:\Windows\System32>dumpbin /exports advapi32.dll | find /I "AsU"
       1140   8A 00034190 CreateProcessAsUserA
       1141   8B 00020560 CreateProcessAsUserW
```

under kernelbase the exported function Address is a place holder for lots of redirected function with a not implemented ErrorReturn

```
0:000> x KernelBase!CreateProcessAsUserW
00000001`80096ab0 KernelBase!CreateProcessAsUserW (void)

0:000> uf KernelBase!CreateProcessAsUserW
KernelBase!IsServerVersionOrAbove:

00000001`80096ab0 4883ec28        sub     rsp,28h
00000001`80096ab4 b97f000000      mov     ecx,7Fh
00000001`80096ab9 48ff1580c41200  call    qword ptr [KernelBase!_imp_RtlSetLastWin32Error (00000001`801c2f40)]
00000001`80096ac0 0f1f440000      nop     dword ptr [rax+rax]
00000001`80096ac5 33c0            xor     eax,eax
00000001`80096ac7 4883c428        add     rsp,28h
00000001`80096acb c3              ret


0:000> ln KernelBase!CreateProcessAsUserW
(00000001`80096ab0)   KernelBase!IsServerVersionOrAbove   |  (00000001`80096ae0)   KernelBase!LsaIExtractTargetInfo
Exact matches:
    KernelBase!GetUrlCacheConfigInfoA (void)
    KernelBase!FwIsValidPorts (void)
    KernelBase!AbortPrinter (void)
    KernelBase!RangeMapCreate (void)
    KernelBase!IsThreadDesktopComposited (void)
    KernelBase!ASN1utctime_cmp (void)
    KernelBase!SetWindowCompositionAttribute (void) 
    XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXcut off XXXXXXXXXXXXXXX
```

the actual implementation also is done at kernelbase.dll at a different Address
(non exported)

```
0:000> x KernelBase!CreateProcessA*
00000001`80096ab0 KernelBase!CreateProcessAsUserA (void)
00000001`80096ab0 KernelBase!CreateProcessAsUserW (void)  <<<<<<< as above
00000001`8010bf50 KernelBase!CreateProcessAsUserA (CreateProcessAsUserA)
00000001`800071c0 KernelBase!CreateProcessA (CreateProcessA)
00000001`80006360 KernelBase!CreateProcessAsUserW (CreateProcessAsUserW) <<<<<<< actual implementation 

0:000> uf 00000001`80006360
KernelBase!CreateProcessAsUserW:
00000001`80006360 4c8bdc          mov     r11,rsp
00000001`80006363 4883ec68        sub     rsp,68h
00000001`80006367 498363f000      and     qword ptr [r11-10h],0
00000001`8000636c 488b8424c0000000 mov     rax,qword ptr [rsp+0C0h]
00000001`80006374 498943e8        mov     qword ptr [r11-18h],rax
00000001`80006378 488b8424b8000000 mov     rax,qword ptr [rsp+0B8h]
00000001`80006380 498943e0        mov     qword ptr [r11-20h],rax
00000001`80006384 488b8424b0000000 mov     rax,qword ptr [rsp+0B0h]
00000001`8000638c 498943d8        mov     qword ptr [r11-28h],rax
00000001`80006390 488b8424a8000000 mov     rax,qword ptr [rsp+0A8h]
00000001`80006398 498943d0        mov     qword ptr [r11-30h],rax
00000001`8000639c 8b8424a0000000  mov     eax,dword ptr [rsp+0A0h]
00000001`800063a3 89442430        mov     dword ptr [rsp+30h],eax
00000001`800063a7 8b842498000000  mov     eax,dword ptr [rsp+98h]
00000001`800063ae 89442428        mov     dword ptr [rsp+28h],eax
00000001`800063b2 488b842490000000 mov     rax,qword ptr [rsp+90h]
00000001`800063ba 498943b8        mov     qword ptr [r11-48h],rax
00000001`800063be e8cd1a0000      call    KernelBase!CreateProcessInternalW (00000001`80007e90)
00000001`800063c3 4883c468        add     rsp,68h
00000001`800063c7 c3              ret
```

there is no symbol match for this address which is pointed by advapi32.dll

```
0:000> ln 00000001`80006360
(00000001`80006360)   KernelBase!CreateProcessAsUserW   |  (00000001`800063d0)   KernelBase!Wow64SetThreadDefaultGuestMachine
Exact matches:
0:000>

0:000> uf /c advapi32!CreateProcessAsUserWStub
advapi32!CreateProcessAsUserWStub (00007ffb`d89d7cc0)
  advapi32!CreateProcessAsUserWStub+0x59 (00007ffb`d89d7d19):
    call to KERNELBASE!CreateProcessAsUserW (00007ffb`d6d96360)
0:000> u 00007ffb`d89d7d19 l2
advapi32!CreateProcessAsUserWStub+0x59:
00007ffb`d89d7d19 48ff1598120600  call    qword ptr [advapi32!_imp_CreateProcessAsUserW (00007ffb`d8a38fb8)]
00007ffb`d89d7d20 0f1f440000      nop     dword ptr [rax+rax]
0:000> dps 00007ffb`d8a38fb8 l1
00007ffb`d8a38fb8  00007ffb`d6d96360 KERNELBASE!CreateProcessAsUserW
0:000>
```

Comment: everything great, but i'm not sure about something. you said that 2 symbols with the same name (`CreateProcessAsUserW`) exist in `KernelBase.dll` and one of them is not exported. how is it even possible that 2 different symbols have the same name?

Comment: + i found out that WinDbg shows `CreateProcessAsUserW` as exported from `advapi32.dll`, but under the name `_imp_CreateProcessAsUserW`, so why dumpbin displays the normal name without the `_imp_` prefix?

Answer (score 1):

When WinDbg has symbols for a module it unfortunately ignores forwarded function exports from the PE exports section.

If you start another WinDbg instance without correct symbols for advapi32 you can do `bp advapi32!CreateProcessAsUserW` etc. This is not a great solution of course.

Just knowing that this happens is usually enough. When you fail to find a function, look in kernelbase (kernel32, advapi32), ntdll (kernel32, user32) or shcore (shlwapi, shell32) instead...